# How to get the address bar and tabs on a different row in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, address-bar

Is it possible to change the layout of IE9 in order to have the address bar be longer or on a different row than the page tabs?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, right click the Internet Explorer frame and click the **Show tabs on a separate row** option.

[image]

Comment: I suppose the other option, to lengthen the address bar is not possible, right?

Comment: You can simply drag-and-drop the edge of the address bar to lengthen/shorten it. (Only if it's on the same row as the tabs, of course.) @Francisc

Comment: @Francisc: You can drag the handle between the address bar in tabs, if you click the option in the above picture the address bar will take more width. I leave them on the same row as I like the new height, I even try not to use a bookmarks bar...

Comment: Hm, I didn't think it would be that easy. Thank you both.

Answer (score 6):

Found it: Right click on the bar and check `Show tabs on separate row`.

Comment: I think you deserved at least my upvote, seeing you answered 1 minute after Tom, all within 5 minutes from the question being asked...

Comment: Haha, I probably didn't refresh the page and only saw his answer after posting mine. It was a long time ago, so I don't remember exactly, but I wouldn't have answered if I had seen his. :)