# Show tabs below the address bar in Internet Explorer 9 

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-9

In older versions of Internet Explorer, the tabs were attached to the content, below the address bar. In IE9, they are on the same row as the address bar. How can I move them back to their old position?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the address bar and tabs on a different row in IE9?](http://superuser.com/questions/257863/how-to-get-the-address-bar-and-tabs-on-a-different-row-in-ie9)

Answer (score 0):

To show tabs below the address bar, **Right-click** the empty space to the right of the **New Tab** button and enable `Show tabs on a separate row`.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: By do this the Tabs are still above the Favorites and Menu bars.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to move the tabs so they are below all other toolbars.